# Combine duplicate hash keys in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I am attempting to take JSON like this:

```
{"myhostname"=>
  {"client"=>"exemplar", "tag"=>"mytag"},
 "mysecondhost"=>
  {"client"=>"exemplar", "tag"=>"mytag2"},
 "myhost2"=>
  {"client"=>"exemplar", "envtag"=>"mytag2"}}
```

My goal is to output something like:

mytag:myhostname
mytag2:mysecondhost, myhost2

It'll need to be JSON at the end of the day, but I'm using pyjojo and that seems to do a good job of reformatting it.  I'm trying to get a list of hosts for each key.

The hostnames are dynamic.  It's been easy to get an output of "tag:host" for each of these, but I'm having a hard time dealing with the situation where the tag is duplicated, and I need to return each host as a comma separated value.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is this `mytag2:mysecondhost, myhost2` ? Your expected output format I am not getting..

Comment: I want to see a list of hosts for any given key.  The use case is that I'm going to target a job to run on a host, and I want select the tag to then populate the list of hosts.  Sometimes a tag will apply to multiple hosts, and thus I need them outputted to one line.  I hope that's more clear.

Comment: as a hash ?... or whay? update your post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remap key value pairs in a JSON object I think you want something like this:

```
hash = { 
         "myhostname"=> {"client"=>"exemplar", "tag"=>"mytag"},
         "mysecondhost"=> {"client"=>"exemplar", "tag"=>"mytag2"},
         "myhost2"=>{"client"=>"exemplar", "envtag"=>"mytag2"}
       }

new_hash = Hash[ 
                 hash.map { |k,h| [k,h.values.last] }.group_by(&:last)
                 .map { |k,v| [k,v.map(&:first)] }
               ]
# => {"mytag"=>["myhostname"], "mytag2"=>["mysecondhost", "myhost2"]}
```

Then iterate through the hash as below:

```
 new_hash.each { |k,v| puts "k: #{v.join(',')}" }
# >> k: myhostname
# >> k: mysecondhost,myhost2
```

*Explanation:*

Look at this [`#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method.

```
# collecting hostname and tag key value as an array
hash.map { |k,h| [k,h.values.last] }
# => [["myhostname", "mytag"],
#     ["mysecondhost", "mytag2"],
#     ["myhost2", "mytag2"]]
```

Look at this [`#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method.

```
# grouping on the tag key's value as to get a below hash
grouped_hash = hash.map { |k,h| [k,h.values.last] }.group_by(&:last)
# => {"mytag"=>[["myhostname", "mytag"]],
#     "mytag2"=>[["mysecondhost", "mytag2"], ["myhost2", "mytag2"]]}

# from the gropued has based on tag key's value, I would collect the tag name and 
# host names associated with the specific tag.
grouped_hash.map { |k,v| [k,v.map(&:first)] }
# => # => [["mytag", ["myhostname"]], ["mytag2", ["mysecondhost", "myhost2"]]]
```

Look at this [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method.

```
# finally got the desired Hash
Hash[grouped_hash.map { |k,v| [k,v.map(&:first)] }]
# => {"mytag"=>["myhostname"], "mytag2"=>["mysecondhost", "myhost2"]}
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you!  I'm going to to go read up on these functions now so I can understand the solution completely.

Comment: You are probably my favorite person on the Internet right now, thank you for being so patient and helping me understand this.  It was really, really helpful.